TypeError: readFile is not a function at PDFLoader.load (langchain) with Jest typescript
i am trying to make a test with Jest in typescript, and i'm running in an error that i can't seem to find the fix to.
I have an express.js backend that has a route '/upload'. The route takes a file from the user:
import { Request, Response } from 'express';
import { FileArray, UploadedFile } from 'express-fileupload';
import { PDFLoader } from 'langchain/document_loaders/fs/pdf';


const uploadDocuments = async (req: Request, res: Response) => {
  const fileUpload: FileArray | null | undefined = req.files;
  // some check ....
  const file = fileUpload[0];
  // some code ...
  const filepath = ...
  const loader = new PDFLoader(filepath);
  const doc = await loader.load();
  console.log(doc);
  return res.send('ok');
}

This code works fine when I run it as usual, the route works well.
Now i'm trying to make a test of this route with Jest.
Here's my jest.config.js:
module.exports = {
  preset: 'ts-jest',
  testEnvironment: 'node',
  collectCoverageFrom: [
    'src/**/*.{ts,tsx}',
    '!**/node_modules/**',
    '!**/vendor/**',
  ],
  moduleDirectories: ["node_modules", 'src'],
  moduleFileExtensions: ["ts", "tsx", "js", "jsx", "json", "cjs", "mjs"],
  verbose: true,
  moduleNameMapper: {
    "fs/promises": "<rootDir>/node_modules/fs-extra/lib/fs"
  },
  transform: {}
};

here is the command i use to start the tests:
"test": "node --experimental-vm-modules --trace-warnings node_modules/jest/bin/jest.js"
Here's my test:
import path from 'path';
import app from '../../../../src/app';
import request from 'supertest';

describe('POST endpoints', () => {
  const endpoint: string = '/api/v1/documents/upload';

  it('should upload a document', async () => {
    const filepath: string = path.join(
      process.cwd(),
      '__tests__/unit/routes/documents/files/test.pdf'
    );
    console.log('filepath: ', filepath);
    const res = await request(app).post(endpoint).attach('files', filepath);
    console.log('res.body: ', res.body);
    console.log('res.body.length: ', res.body.length);

    expect(res.statusCode).toEqual(200);
    expect(res.body.length).toEqual(1);
    expect(res.body).toContain([
      {
        filename: 'test.pdf',
        success: false, // for now can't make it work as i always get "readFile is not a function" error
      },
    ]);
  });
});

However when I run it i get this error:
TypeError: readFile is not a function
        at PDFLoader.load (/some_path/node_modules/.pnpm/langchain@0.1.36_chromadb@1.8.1_mammoth@1.7.2_officeparser@4.0.8_openai@4.40.1_pdf-parse@1.1.1_vectordb@0.4.18/node_modules/langchain/dist/document_loaders/fs/buffer.cjs:34:28)
        at PDFLoader.loadAndSplit (/some_path/node_modules/.pnpm/langchain@0.1.36_chromadb@1.8.1_mammoth@1.7.2_officeparser@4.0.8_openai@4.40.1_pdf-parse@1.1.1_vectordb@0.4.18/node_modules/langchain/dist/document_loaders/base.cjs:17:22)

I am using :
    "jest": "^29.7.0",
    "@langchain/community": "^0.0.52",
    "@langchain/core": "^0.1.60",
    "@langchain/openai": "^0.0.28",
    "@types/cookie-parser": "^1.4.7",
    "@types/express-fileupload": "^1.5.0",
    "pdf-parse": "^1.1.1",

Has anyone encountered this kind of issues ?
I tried to change the jest config, the packages versions but i can't find anything that makes it works.
